# Make pagination from SVN file log

Tags: php, apache, svn, pagination

I want to make a 'pagination' from SVN file log. E.g. revision can be 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, my page is 1st, 3 items per page. So i can use `svn log -r 50:1 -l 3 repo.url/file.ext` to take 50, 45 and 40 revs. But how i can know about from what revision take next request, e.g. for page 3 (must be 20, 15, 10)? There is no `skip n` parameter in `svn log`, so i can't call `svn log -r 50:1 -l 3 --skip (page*perPage)`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but here goes. While I sincerely hope that @denn found an answer **long long ago**, I leave this here to help future google-searchers.

I think the simplest answer would be to run a for/do loop from 1 to the HEAD revision. Note that since you did not specify an OS, I'm writing this in PowerShell and should be able to tweak it to whatever you need.

```
####################################################################
####################################################################
### These two variables are the only ones you need to customize
###     for your own environment/needs.
###
### Note that it may take some experimentation to determine the best
###     value for $LogPerPg; I have set '5' here to follow @denn's example.
####################################################################
# If you want the log for the entire repository, leave off the "/FolderPath"
#   (remember to remove that final slash too)

$SvnPath         = 'https://SvnPath/RepoName/FolderPath'

# Set the number of log entries to show per page
#   and initialize its variable as an integer

[int]$LogPerPg   = 5

####################################################################
####################################################################

# The '--show-item revision' parameter will retrieve the revision number of the HEAD
[int]$MaxRev     = $(svn info --show-item revision $SvnPath)

# Initialize these variables as integers
[int]$RevCount   = 0
[int]$RevUpper   = 0
[int]$RevLower   = 0

# Loop through from $MaxRev down to 1
for (
    # Set the max bound for the entire loop
    $RevCount=$MaxRev
    # Determine the condition that will cause the loop to stop
    $RevCount -gt 0
    # Perform an action after each loop is completed
    $RevCount = $RevCount - $LogPerPg

) {
    # Determine if this will be the final loop or not
    if ( $RevCount -ge $LogPerPg ) {
        # Note that this same formula inside the FOR condition is only applied
        #   AFTER the loop, so it is necessary to repeat it inside the loop to
        #   establish a lower bound
        $RevLower = $RevCount - $LogPerPg
    } else {
        $RevLower = 1
    }

    # Set the upper revision for this loop
    $RevUpper = $RevCount

    # Run the log between established bounds
    & svn log -r"${RevUpper}:${RevLower}" $SvnPath

    # Note that this method **only** accepts the <Enter> key.
    Read-Host -Prompt "`n`nPress <Enter> to see the next $LogPerPg revisions"

    # Uncomment the next line if you would like the screen to clear between each iteration
    # Clear-Host
}

####################################################################
# Final note: I have demonstrated how to display the logs from 
#   HEAD back to 1. If you want to see from 1 up to HEAD, read on
#   A. replace the following lines: 
#        33:    $RevCount=1
#        35:        $RevCount -le $MaxRev
#        37:        $RevCount = $RevCount + $LogPerPg
#        41:    if ( $RevCount -ge ( $MaxRev - $LogPerPg ) ) {
#        45:        $RevLower = $RevCount + $LogPerPg
#        47:        $RevLower = $MaxRev
#        51:    $RevUpper = $RevCount
#
#   B. For reading-logic, you will also want to reverse all instances 
#   of $RevLower and $RevUpper throughout the entire script
####################################################################
```

**Note**: I use tab-expansion of 4 spaces; if you use a different value, your indents may look different than mine.